# How to modify this function for PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im using Static MySQL PDO class on my website which was prepared beforehands by someone else. and this function is to check user input (i.e. username,messages.)

**There are 2 problems.** 
First of all, since Im new at PDO, I'm having difficulties to understand this function due to its syntax eventhough I have debugged it before step by step. Yes, It controls the input but I wanna know how it does it exactly?

Secondly I'm running PHP 5.4 and as I read everywhere get_magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated. If this is the case, I wanna know how I can modify it in parts?

The function is:

```
public static function control($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") {
        $theValue = trim($theValue);
        $theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
```

The class that I'm using uploaded here. [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/212a73f2de5785783e001d64881156be5d4c9e3b)

Comment: Using pdo this function would appear to corrupt the data by adding slashes (as if you are using pdo you will probably be using parameterised queries, and a bound parameter does not need escaping). Having get_magic_quotes_gpc() could cause you problems. Further even if you are not using pdo, addslashes is quite an obsolete method of escaping values to use in an SQL query.

Comment: "I read everywhere get_magic_quotes_gpc is not deprecated anymore." The *function* isn't, but the magic quotes "feature" itself was removed in PHP 5.4. In 5.4+ it'll just return false at all times.

Comment: Lets clarify this then to see If I really need it or not. because It doesnt seem anything corrupted so far. I've attached the class that Im using to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your function:-

```
$theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
```

This line checks if magic quotes is on (which it won't be). If it is on then it just takes the value, if it is off (which it will be now) it uses addslashes to escape most characters that will cause problems.

Using the example in the php documentations, if you use addslashes on the string *Is your name O'Reilly?* it would return *Is your name O\'Reilly?* . For basic escaping of data this works.

The fucntion for a text field then does:-

```
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
```

which is checking if it is empty or not. If empty then it returns NULL, if not it returns the escaped variable with quotes added to the ends. So *Is your name O'Reilly?* becomes *'Is your name O\'Reilly?'* . The back slash tells php that the following single quote is to be treated as a value of a single quote, and not interpreted as a quote that ends the string.

This value is returned. This is only really useful if you are just building up a string of SQL and executing it though.

Say the value was the user name of *O'Reilly* and you wanted to check if that user existed, what you want is something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'O\'Reilly'
```

If it wasn't escaped you would have:-

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'O'Reilly'
```

Which would give an error. It would also mean that someone could have entered the user name of *fred' OR 1=1* , so the query would ALWAYS return a row. This is basic **SQL injection**.

Addslashes() was the very basic way of escaping strings. For MySQL this was replaced by mysql_escape_string() , and that was replaced by mysql_real_escape_string(), each more secure than the one before.

PDO is normally used to allow parameterised queries. For these you set up a query with markers in it for where you want the variable. So maybe *SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username* , where :username is a place holder for the variable. You then bind the variable to that placeholder. As it is passed as a variable in this way it doesn't matter about the quote as that quote is part of the variable, not part of the string of SQL, thus in theory preventing SQL injection.

However if you have escaped the variable and added quotes to it before binding it to the SQL statement, when you wanted to look for **O'Reilly** you have instead looked for **'O\'Reilly'** (complete with quotes and the back slash).

So if you are really using pdo properly with bound values then this function is not required. If you are just using pdo instead of mysql_* functions, and building up the string then this function is still required, but is fairly insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The important question is; At last paragraph you said " if you are really using pdo properly with bound values...", Referring to the class in the link that I have added to the question afterwards, do you think it will be secure to i.e. use `$username = $_POST['username'], 'text');` and add $username directly to DB::getRow query. Do you think PDO is used properly to not to need this function ?

Comment: @leg0las - The class you added does not appear to bind explicitly bind any variables. The method to escape a variable is not required with bound parameters. It does allow an array of parameters to be passed, and these would not need to be escaped. Check the manual page on it - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php . As a bound parameter you could just use $_POST variables. Something like _$fred = new DB(); $fred->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", array(':username'=>'burt'));_

Answer (score -1):

For the poper use with PDO this function should be as follows

```
public static function control($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = ""){
    return $theValue;
}
```

then you can use the returned value to bind it to a placeholder using bindValue() with PDO.

Comment: Really, for proper use this function should go away entirely, as PDO handles it all.

Comment: Learn how to spell. "poper" isn't a word in the dictionary.